# Do all autoencoders perform dimensionality reduction

Tags: neural-network, autoencoder, dimensionality-reduction

I want to use Convolutional autoencoder to find patterns in data as well as reduce dimensions. Can it be used for this purpose? Moreover, is removal of multicollinear features through autoencoder better than manual feature selection(plotting correlation and stuff)?